# What do I need to set to make a custom attribute available for related product rules?

Tags: product, attributes

I have a custom attribute, and I want my product page to display other products that also have the same value for this attribute. But, when I go to the related product rules configuration page, I don't see this attribute in the list! How do I make it available for use by related products?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the manage attributes page for that attribute, and set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes".